# WSO2 Stratos OpenStack network ID

Tags: wso2, openstack, wso2-stratos

People, do you know option to set OpenStack net-id for [Stratos](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/Home) deployment? 
I believe, there should be an option in `cloud-controller.xml`, but I see no definition of it.

Comment: Please mention the stratos version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the network to use to spawn the instance, in the cartridge definition you can do so by adding a `networkInterfaces` section in the `iaasProvider` as follows.

```
"networkInterfaces":[
        {
        "name":"net0",
        "networkUuid":"c465e4bc-b272-487b-915b-a3f52f82167a"
        }
        ],
```